# While debugging in eclipse the code navigation buttons get disabled, the stackframe also is not visible

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

Its a very common problem that I face, when I a debug a large Java application and on pressing the resume button I face this issue that the "step over", "step into" and "step return" all seems to be disabled.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kYQH.png): [image: Here is the picture of my debug view in eclipse, the navigational buttons are disabled.]

What could be the issue here?

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pressing <kbd>resume</kbd>, and until some breakpoint is reached by at least one running thread, the <kbd>step *</kbd> buttons are not available, since they can only be used when a thread has been interrupted by a breakpoint.

There are other possibilities, but only if you have clicked somewhere in the Debug window of the Debug perspective: when a thread is stopped because it has reached a breakpoint, then clicking on another stack frame for the same thread in the Debug window may disable <kbd>step into</kbd> and <kbd>step return</kbd>, and clicking on the same window in any frame of another thread that has not reached a breakpoint will disable everything instead of <kbd>suspend</kbd> and <kbd>terminate</kbd>.

As a global rule, you need to take into account the state of the specific thread you select in the Debug window of the Debug perspective, and the frame you select in the stack frame of this thread, to anticipate which buttons are enabled/disabled. Because the state of the buttons depend on those choices.

Comment: This is one possibility, but is this the only possibility?

Comment: There are other possibilities, but only if you have clicked somewhere in the Debug window of the Debug perspective: when a thread is stopped because it has reached a breakpoint, then clicking on another stack frame for the same thread in the Debug window may disable *step into* and *step return*, and clicking on the same window in any frame of another thread that has not reached a breakpoint will disable everything instead of *suspend* and *terminate*.

Comment: Please kindly update your answer with this info as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i have better understanding of this, can you point some online resource on debugging

Comment: You will find many tutorials for debugging on Eclipse. But what is very important to understand, is that the concepts are the same with many other languages on many other runtimes. Debugging Java running in the JVM is really the same as debugging a C program compiled and running on Windows or Unix. So I would suggest that after having read some of the tutorials about debugging on Eclipse, you read the following page about debugging a C program with GDB: you may be surprised by the concepts that are strictly the same: http://phoenix.thch.unipg.it/manuals/gdb/gdb_7.html#SEC41